# Cut a string into different sections in PHP?

Tags: php, html, function

I'm fairly new to PHP and I need to cut a string up into certain sections based on value, not character count.

I've heard of the explode function and the substring but I don't know how to use it to achieve what I want.

I've got an output string: 
`Name: example Email: e.g@example.com Website: http://examples.com/ Comment: this is where the comment goes, we can't use explode because there's lots of spaces here Another comment: this is another comment Some random info: this is more info...`

I want to display this info in separate lines for aesthetic purposes.

Is there a way to return a word after a specific word but before another specific word?

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays?

Comment: @Haudegen with all due respect, OP cannot figure out explode and substring right now and you're suggesting REGEX?

Comment: Haha, I know what RegEx is, but I have NO clue how to use it. I also know what substring does, but that's cutting a string with character count, I'm not looking for that. Explode also isn't helpful because I've got nothing separating the different parts of the string (e.g. name: name; email: email;)

Comment: Before you can even think about using regular expressions you need to work out if the thing you are trying to parse is regular. Will the input always take the same format with just the "data" varying or will the input always vary. I notice you have "Another Comment" and that break the regularity of XXX: or one word followed by a colon, being your identifier, so the only way to do it is to know all the "keys" for the data and to parse the string looking for them.

Comment: You are asking for something hair-pullingly impossible because there is no rhyme or reason for any method to ever acieve 100% accuracy. Are you controlling this string's format? If so then use JSON and stop trying to re-invent the wheel to become a 2-sided triangle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this, provided the given string is ***always*** in a regular format.

Using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) might form the basis:

```
$arr = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The regular expression splits the given string at a point immediately before any uppercase letter by using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion.

If we do a `print_r()` on the array, you can see the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name: example 
    [1] => Email: e.g@example.com 
    [2] => Website: http://examples.com/ 
    [3] => Comment: this is where the comment goes ... 
    [4] => Another comment: this is another comment 
    [5] => Some random info: this is more info...
)
```

How do you get this string in the first place? If that's something under your control, then I **strongly** recommend using JSON or similar for transferring data. It's way easier and less buggy - and you can be sure that it works.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. I was wondering, if the contents of the value (that is assuming key:value) had a capital character, how will the splitting regex change? What I mean is something like this - "Name: Example". Is there anyway to do that using split?

Comment: @Yeah: Interesting problem. I'll try to find a solution! Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Yeah: Something like this should work `(?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s*:\s*)`. See demo: https://eval.in/102804

Comment: Awesome... I couldn't figure it out this way. Working on your regex, I think this is more complete(pertaining to the question above) - `/(?=[A-Z][a-z\s]*:)/`. See this - http://codepad.org/mTiCqJIo

Answer (score 2):

This works -

```
$regex = "/[A-Z][^A-Z]*?\:\s.*?(?(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]*?\:)|$)/";
$string = "Name: Example Email: e.g@example.com Website: http://examples.com/ Comment: this is where the comment goes, we can't use explode Because there's Lots of spaces here Another comment: this is another comment Some random info: this is more info";
if(preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches)){
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
/*
OUTPUT
array
  0 => string 'Name: Example ' (length=14)
  1 => string 'Email: e.g@example.com ' (length=23)
  2 => string 'Website: http://examples.com/ ' (length=30)
  3 => string 'Comment: this is where the comment goes, we can't use explode Because there's Lots of spaces here ' (length=98)
  4 => string 'Another comment: this is another comment ' (length=41)
  5 => string 'Some random info: this is more info' (length=35)

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple string manipulation functions like this & make ur life simple..

```
<?php
      $strx='Name: example Email: user@example.com Website: http://example.com/';
      $str=stristr($strx,"Comment :",true);// Take all chars before 'Comments :'
      $str= str_replace(": ",":",str);
      $str = str_replace(" ","\n");          
      echo $str . '\n Comment : '. ; // Its 
      echo stristr($strx,"Comment :"); // Done
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the `explode()` function is what you are looking for but it won't work too well on your example since you are missing some unique characters for separation. With something like:

```
Name: example; Email: e.g@example.com; Website: http://example.com/
```

You could for example explode the string by the semicolons. [explode() tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, there's no unique character and I can't use space because the info fields contain spaces.

Comment: @user3313191: `explode()` won't work for this case. You can use `preg_split()` instead. Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21858534/1438393).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a REGEX that will pull out each part that you are asking for:

```
<?php

$string = "Name: example Email: e.g@example.com Website: http://examples.com/ Comment: this is where the comment goes, we can't use explode because there's lots of spaces here Another comment: this is another comment Some random info: this is more info... ";

$name = '';
$email = '';
$website = '';

if (preg_match('/^Name: ([-A-Z \'.]+) Email: ([-A-Z0-9_@.]+) Website: ([-A-Z0-9\/.:]+) /i', $string, $matches)) {
    $name = $matches[1];
    $email = $matches[2];
    $website = $matches[3];
}

print '
    Name: '.$name.'
    Email: '.$email.'
    Website: '.$website;
```

Comment: With the updated question - there's a `Comment:` block at the end - so if you'll need to tweak that RegExp accordingly (the line terminator after the website will kill it) - but otherwise yeah, if you need to manipulate strings there's nothing better or more flexible than Regular Expressions IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on a capital letter, assuming your titles always start with one.

```
$text = "Name: example Email: e.g@example.com Website: http://examples.com/ Comment: this    is where the comment goes, we can't use explode because there's lots of spaces here Another comment: this is another comment Some random info: this is more info...";
$test = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $text);
foreach($test AS $line){
    echo $line."<br />";
}
```